# The person who puts food on plate?

Tags: single-word-requests

In places such as cafeterias, there are people who put food on our plates, and I want to know what I can call them.

Comment: You mean in some airport restaurants where the person behind the counter places your meal on the plate. Not the waiter/waitress/server who brings your meal to your table. If it is a British school canteen, they are usually called *dinner ladies*.

Comment: What does it mean to "put food on plate"? I'm not familiar with this idiom.

Comment: Like a client and a server ?

Comment: I would call them "servers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Food attendant](http://work.chron.com/job-description-food-attendant-17704.html)*** or ***food counter attendant*** may refer to the  activity you are describing:

> - Food attendants greet customers and answer their questions about meal specials or specific diet requests. ***They also prepare and serve meals for dining in, carryout or from drive-thru windows, and replenish stocking stations with utensils, condiments, napkins and drinking cups***. Some work in dining rooms, clearing tables for customers, cleaning them and setting them up for new arrivals. Those working on food assembly lines work as teams, ensuring meals are accurate and served at the proper temperatures.

(work.chron.com)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Line Server

Or

> Food Line Server

Comment: Or just *server*.